# Rospack failed to build

Tags: rosmake, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to make a system-wide installation in OpenSUSE to be used by different users. As such I have installed ROS in /opt/ros. I managed to install ROS with no problems and even compiled some additional packages in the system-wide installation.

I was now trying to compile some user packages in the user home folder. I did the following:

1. Created a folder "mystacks" in the user folder;
2. Used roscreate-pkg to create the package in a folder inside the "mystacks" folder;
3. Added "mystacks" full path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

The problem now is that when I run rosmake with my package name I get "Rospack failed to build". Even running "rosmake --help" results in the same error!

Since I am building this package in the user folder, it should not be a permissions problem, and ROS does not have a problem finding the package. Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced,

Hugo Costelha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10517/rospack-failed-to-build/) by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be a permissions problem.
rosmake will recursively build dependencies and thus also go into the /opt/ros directory for building.

If you have packages prebuilt there manually that you know are built properly, you can touch ROS_NOBUILD to prevent compilation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2011-07-15**:
Ok. I have been taking a look at the Ubuntu packages, and see that there is a ROS_NOBUILD in every package folder in order to prevent just that. I see also that I can simply run make, which will not make any dependecies (don't know if there are other implications in running make instead of rosmake)